# problem sending mail from backend file not found iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

i'm trying to use the skpsmtpmessage to send emails from backend. In the README.txt it says:

To use this in your app include the following files in your project:

SKPSMTPMessage.*
NSStream+SKPSMTPExtensions.*

That should mean that i have to include the .h .m files in my project. Now, after i've done that i get an error NSData+Base64Additions.h not found, so i imported the missing classes for this 'skpsmtpmessage' project but i get tons of errors like:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_kCFStreamSSLLevel", referenced from:
      -[SKPSMTPMessage parseBuffer] in SKPSMTPMessage.o
```

i get the same errors if i even remove the import lines. I cleaned the project but it doesn't help at all.

Has anyone used this library before? Have you experienced this errors before? I need some guide.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the header files for the project you've downloaded. You'll see this:

```
#import <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h>
```

This means that the class uses the **CFNetwork** framework. You will need to add it to your project in Xcode and make sure that your target links against the framework.

Comment: Dude, you're my own personal Jesus Christ. Thanks!!